# Where to store Jenkinsfile for downstream pipeline without its own repo

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, artifact, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm in the process of setting up Jenkins pipeline jobs for our build. We previously used Freestyle jobs to build each of our repos, with various extra manually triggered jobs at the packaging and deployment stages.

We have the following Pipeline setup so far:

- repo A/Jenkinsfile - Pipeline A - build, runs unit tests and produces
  artifact
- repo B/Jenkinsfile - Pipeline B - build, runs unit tests and
  produces artifact

Whenever Pipeline A or B completes I want to run Pipeline C.

- Pipeline C should take the artifacts of the latest A and B pipelines, package them together as a docker image, run integration tests, deploy to staging environment.

**Where should I store the Jenkinsfile for Pipeline C since it does not have it's own source repo?**

To me this logically sits as a separate pipeline that is downstream from A and B so assume this belongs in a separate Jenkinsfile but then where would that go in source control. To clarify I would like to have all my pipeline files under source control.

**Alternatively should I try to define the whole pipeline (including integration, etc.) in just one of the parent Pipelines**, skipping the build part when it is triggered from the other pipeline? Leaving the other as a simple build. For example

- Pipeline A (full pipeline)

  - build
  - unit tests
  - artifact
  - (get latest B artifact)
  - integration test
  - deploy to staging
- Pipeline B (simple build that then uses full pipeline)

  - build
  - unit tests
  - artifact
  - trigger Pipeline A, skipping everything up to integration test step *(potentially using `when` blocks on those stages that look at the build trigger?)*

I can find resources on either building or triggering one pipeline from another like this: https://metamorphant.de/blog/posts/2019-03-11-jenkins-101-downstream-projects/
but no information on structuring the above kind of dependencies and pipelines in Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: Pipeline C can sit in either of the repositories, you just need to point to this Jenkinsfile in the configuration of your job C.

Comment: @DibakarAditya that's what I'm going to try. I'm not 100% convinced that's the logical place for it, however that seems better than creating a new repo/project just to store the single Pipeline C file. Maybe once I've got a full suite of integration tests I'll put those and the Pipeline C file in a repo together.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a 'new item' in Jenkins and select the 'Pipeline' project type, you get a form when the Pipeline is defaulted to 'Pipeline script'. 
If you have a Jenkinsfile, then you switch to use 'Pipeline script from SCM' and sets it to point to the GIT location of the Jenkinsfile, but if you leave it to be 'Pipeline script' as defaulted, you can put the content of the Pipeline inside the form, and it will be saved inside the job's config.xml file, without the need to store it in source control.

Comment: You're right that would solve the problem but your answer made me realise I hadn't stated that I want all my pipeline files under source control. I have now edited my answer to explicitly state that.